# Generic method type erasure and pattern matching

Tags: scala, type-erasure

This example compiles with warning for type erasure

```
final case class InvBox[A](b: A)

def maybeeq[A, B](x: InvBox[A], y: InvBox[B]): A = y match {
   case _ : x.type => y.b
}
```

And this one can't be compiled because two singleton types are different

```
def maybeeq[A, B](x: InvBox[A], y: InvBox[B]): Unit = {
   implicitly[x.type =:= y.type]
}
```

Why type erasure effects first example and allowed to prove that "y" is "x.type" on compile time, but makes it impossible to compile code in the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to match `x.type` with `y.type` at compile time, because at compile time `A` and `B` is not known. And implicits is a compile time mechanism.

Comment: but how compiler accepts that y.b is A? I supposed it should happen before type erasure

Comment: Furthermore, `x.type` is not `InvBox[A]`, but it is the singleton type of `x`, which only `x` has.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Why is that? I check and it proves you are right (https://ideone.com/XdsUEm) but why is that?

Comment: It's a design decision by the language authors.

Answer (score 1):

> Why type erasure effects first example and allowed to prove that "y" is "x.type" on compile time

It doesn't prove this. This match may fail. It only succeeds when `x` and `y` are the same object (`x eq y` is `true`), so in the branch `y` must also have type `InvBox[A]` (because `x` does) and `y.b` will have type `A`.

I am actually surprised it compiles: the Scala compiler doesn't normally do this kind of type refinement (i.e. changing the known type of `y` depending on local information from matching it).